# Viewbag changes value in onclick?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

So I'm using a viewbag in a pretty large MVC application.
(I know Viewbag isn't that great but I had to continue programming in the same style as previous developers for obvious reasons)

Today I stumbled upon a very weird problem with viewbag to me. I was trying to call a javascript function in an onclick function using the viewbag values as parameters. The function does a redirection, the function works fine but for some reason my viewbag value changes??

The IncludeAcknowledged value changes from `True` to `onclick` in the function.

Here is my code I used (with some temporary debug thingies):
html:

```
@ViewBag.IncludeAcknoweldge @*displays true*@
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="javascript:Common.loadUrl('IncidentMonitor/List/?Date=@ViewBag.DateTime&IncludeAcknowledged=@ViewBag.IncludeAcknoweldged&Source=@ViewBag.Source&SourceId=@ViewBag.SourceId');">@Resources.ButtonCancel</button>
@ViewBag.IncludeAcknoweldged @*displays true*@
```

I can also see True when placing a breakpoint near it. 
But in the inspector of the web-browser it just shows:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="javascript:Common.loadUrl('IncidentMonitor/List/?Date=&amp;IncludeAcknowledged=onclick&amp;Source=&amp;SourceId=');">Annuleren</button>
```

Any idea why this is happening? I can probably work around but would really like to know why it behaves like this.

edit: did a workaround by doing:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick='loadUrl()'>@Resources.ButtonCancel</button>
<script>
function loadUrl() {
    javascript:Common.loadUrl("IncidentMonitor/List/Date=@ViewBag.DateTime&IncludeAcknowledged=@ViewBag.IncludeAcknoweldged&Source=@ViewBag.Source&SourceId=@ViewBag.SourceId");
    }
</script>
```

But would still like to know an answer why the workaround is correct while putting the function in the onclick gives the weird viewbag value.

edit2:
As requested several times the controller code of the action... although there is not much to see because I never touched my variable elsewhere:

```
[HttpGet]
        [AuthorizeFunctionality(RequestedFunctionality.Editor)]
        public ActionResult Edit()
        {

            try
            {

                var editIncidentEventContainer = new EditIncidentViewModel
                {
                };

                ViewBag.IncludeAcknoweldged = true;

                return View("_Edit", editIncidentEventContainer);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary{{ "controller", "Error" },
                    { "action", "DisplayMessage" },
                    { "message", ex.Message }});
            }
        }
```

Comment: How is `IncludeAcknoweldge` set?

Comment: In the controller it is simply set to true or false depending on an expression. I have changed that code to `ViewBag.Acknoweldged = True;` to see if there was nothing wrong with that part.

Comment: Try `...&IncludeAcknowledged=@ViewBag.IncludeAcknoweldged.ToString()&...`

Comment: Can you include your controller code in the question?

Comment: Show us the code where you set the value of the `ViewBag`

Comment: @counterflux - You can delete the controller code - it has nothing to do with the issue. Its because `Razor 2` (MVC-4) introduced conditional attributes and this is an unfortunate side effect. You need to use `.ToString()` with boolean properties. [This article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/201/Cleaner-Conditional-HTML-Attributes-In-Razor-Web-Pages) explains conditional attributes in more detail

Comment: @StephenMuecke So Razor made it like this for attributes like checked etc. Passing a true/false  to it is indeed easier and I can understand why they did it this way. Thank you! Is it ever usefull on the onclick event? (Would be nice to post it again as an answer maybe? this is the 6th comment and is just hidden)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you seeing is an unfortunate side affect of a feature added in MVC-4/Razor-2.0 called conditional attributes.

Prior to MVC-4, if you wanted to manually generate (say) a checkbox and set the `checked` attribute based on a model property, if was necessary to include messy conditional statements in the markup to set the `checked` attribute. With conditional attributes, you can simply use

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="@ViewBag.IsChecked" ... />
```

and if `IsChecked` is `true` it will output `checked="checked"` and if `false` the attribute will be omitted.

In MVC-4+, you now need to use `.ToString()` to force razor to evaluate the value as a `string` rather than a `bool`, in your case

```
onclick="...&IncludeAcknowledged=@ViewBag.IncludeAcknoweldged.ToString()&..."
```

Note that the reason your second option works is that its not being evaluated inside a html attribute.

You can read more about conditional attributes in [this article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/201/Cleaner-Conditional-HTML-Attributes-In-Razor-Web-Pages).

Answer (score 0):

Using parentheses around ViewBag might do the trick:
`@(ViewBag.IncludeAcknoweldge)`

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems with using ViewBag is that keys are not checked (no compile time check, no runtime check). And you seem to be using several different spellings for possibly the same variable:

```
ViewBag.IncludeAcknoweldge
ViewBag.IncludeAcknoweldged
```

Perhaps fixing this will fix your problem?

Comment: I noticed when reviewing my edits I made a mistake in giving additional code. I edited IncludeAcknoweldged to Acknoweldged in my program to see it had nothing to do with an unfortunate naming. I rechecked spelling but all is fine. Also even if I would have misspelled the variable I would get something like "undefined" or "null" instead of "onclick".